# Why is my granddaughter screaming in the middle of the night like something is wrong but calms down in about 10-15 min?

Tags: toddler, behavior, sleep, grandparents

My granddaughter wakes up around 1:30 every night screaming and tightening her body up like something is going on. This just started about a week ago. Could she be having a bad dream?

Comment: See https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/18240/11210