# 4 year old wakes up in hysterics, crying with eyes closed

Tags: toddler, naps

It started happening at night which we assumed to be night terrors, but now he’s waking up after short naps in the car.  He’s inconsolable and any efforts to comfort him are forcibly rejected.  Just wondering g if night terrors can happen during naps? I say during, because in these episodes it always ends within him crying for several minutes then finding his way back to sleep when the attempts to comfort him fail.

Comment: I'm wondering if you have noticed his breathing right before one of these events?  It would be unusual, but sleep apnea can happen to kids, and cause terrifying nightmares.

Comment: Sounds like it. It usually happens at a set amount of time after falling asleep, so it can happen during a nap. Not a duplicate, but does this help? https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/18204/9327

Comment: I feel for you! This happened with our 4 year old as well and it was always a battle. Our problem though, was he loves dinosaurs and we used to let him watch his favorite dino show. Once we were out of ideas and options, I took TV away completely. It fixed the issue! We slowly introduced media back and narrowed it down. His favorite Dino show was the cause of his night terrors. We no longer watch that and he has never had night terrors again. Not saying it's the same issue, but it could be worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like 'night terrors' even though it happens at naptime, too. My son did this. One night during his 'episode', I whispered, "shhhh, you'll wake up the baby." He woke up right away and was able to get back to sleep without a problem. It turned out that my son just wasn't getting enough sleep. Once he did, it went away.

Try getting your son to wind down earlier than usual, perhaps 15-30 minutes, gradually setting his bedtime to an earlier hour. Don't expect it to be an instant change, but it should resolve the problem without a recurrence.